# Excel Save Progress Bar Doesnt Go Away After It Saves

Tags: excel

When I save my Excel Workbook, it does appear to save (I checked the file details in the explorer window) but the green progress bar still sits on the screen.

Any idea how to get it to close or even hide it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you go away from the keyboard for 5 minutes? Is it still there after you return?

Comment: Yeah it appeared to be sitting there, and I can close it, but it still saved. I kept playing around with what I had been doing in Excel and it seems back to normal now, not sure why it got stuck like that for a bit.

Comment: How big is the file? Can you try to save it as `xlsb` and try again?

Comment: Do you have any Excel Add-Ins running (that might be causing this)?  Try this VBA fix: hit [Alt+F11] --> [Ctrl+G] --> Type "Application.StatusBar = False"--> Hit [Enter]